# How to connect HC-06 with HC-08 with the HC-06 as master and HC-08 as slave?

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth

How do you connect HC-06 with HC-08 with the HC-06 as master and HC-08 as slave? I will try it using 2 Arduino Unos.

Comment: Ok sorry. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. The HC-06 is a slave only device.

So you need to use a device as master, that is actually capable of it. I don't know, if the HC-08 can do it. Another typical bluetooth master device is the HC-05. Just like HC-06, but can also be a master.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help.